# updating a data feed checking for new and current values

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am going to set up a cron job to update some data via an API. I want it to update the database with the new feeds.

i.e. I would have an existing feed of entries, a script would go through the new feed. If the entry is already there, then dont update, if it is not in the db, then add it, and all other entries need to be deleted.

I was wondering what a good way to do this was have a column called "updated". This would be 0 by default. When a new entry is added, or an existing one is checked, the columns value becomes 1. Once the cron job has completed its updating, it would then remove all values that are still 0, and reset the remainder to 0.

Is this the right way to do such a job, if it helps there are over 10 million rows.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no right or wrong answer and it always depends.

Now that being said with your approach you'll be updating **all 10m+** rows in your main (target) table twice each time you do the sync up, which depending on how busy this table is may or may not be acceptable.

You may consider a different approach that is widely used in ETL:

1. load your feed data into a staging table first; do batch inserts or if possible use `LOAD DATA INFILE` - the fastest way of ingesting data in MySQL
2. optionally build indexes to help with lookups
3. "massage" your data if necessary (clean up, transform, augment etc)
4. insert into main table all new rows that present in staging and not in the main table
5. delete all rows from the main table that don't present in the staging table
6. truncate staging table